# Father of 3 children got problems with the UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, denmark, england

I'm a father of two daughters under 18 years old and a son over 18 years old. We have lived in Denmark for years, and my children are born here, but only my over 18 year old son has Danish nationality.

My daughters and I have got what the Danes call "opholdstilladelse"(-in english a residence permit) so we are still Sri Lankan nationalities.

We want to visit some family in the UK, but we are kind of stuck in the whole visa applying [website](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa?utm_source=visa-application-form&utm_medium=internal-link&utm_campaign=svv-apply-visa).

1. Do we each have to make our own visa application (My daughters and I)?
2. If my son is a Danish citizen, is it true, that the rest of the family doesn't need to pay for our visas? (I've just heard some people talking about that)

I hope someone can help me fastest as possible, my children really need this vacation for once.

Comment: Regarding question 2, Your son has the right to travel anywhere in the EU without a visa. If you are traveling **with him**, you can get a visa for free and with fewer questions.

Comment: @o.m. The family will not qualify for free visas under the freedom of movement directive unless they can allow they qualify as "extended family members"; this may be possible if they all live together, because then they will be members of the same household, but it's not clear to me whether the UK interpretation of that term would cover the present situation.

Comment: @phoog, the UK seems to say that living together is enough, and that's how I interpreted the OP. https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/607824/Extended-family-members-v4.pdf